# Вывод картинки на страницу товара по ID товара

Tags: php

Доброго дня, такой вопрос. Как при помощи php можно реализовать вывод картинки в определенных товарах (например по id товара) на сайте. Шаблон у всех товаров один, соответственно если вставить просто как `<a href="ссыль" ><img  src="путь картины" ></a>` то отобразится на всех имеющихся товарах. Кто-то сталкивался с таким?

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто: нужно написать шаблон, к примеру, в виде php скрипта. Когда нужно вывести блок с товаром - нужно просто подключить нужный шаблон. Пример кода:

1. Есть код с массивом товаров

   ```
   <?php
   $goods = [
       1 => [
       'link'=>'http://yandex.ru/',
       'img'=>'http://yandex.ru/favicon.ico'
       ]
   ];
   foreach ($goods as $item) {
       include 'template.php';
   }
   ?>
   ```
2. И простой php шаблон блока товара *template.php*.

   ```
   <div><a href="<?= $item['link']; ?>">
   <?php if (isset($item['img'])): ?>
   <img src="<?= $item['img']; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
   </a></div>
   ```

Все что нужно сделать: подключить шаблон, а он проверит наличие ссылки на картинку, и если она есть - выведет тег `<img>` со ссылкой на картинку. Иначе - будет пустой тег `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

При формировании HTML шаблоны **парсятся** - то есть подставляются нужные данные в определенные места шаблона. Вот и надо подставить нужный путь картинки, в момент формирования HTML.

Comment: Не совсем о том говорил. Допустим, у меня есть товары с ID'ами 1,2,3,4,5,6. Мне нужно вывести див с картинкой только на товарах с ID'ами 1, 4 , 6. Как вот это реализовать?

Comment: Или изначально не показывать не нужные картинки, или, если нужно без перезагрузки страницы показывать картинки для разных товаров, то использовать, например, jquery. Изначально подгружать на страницу все картинки, а потом управлять их видимостью - типа `$(#id2).find('img').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется лучше реализовать на `php` проверку. Задаём в админке для товара, например, `radio`, задаем выше для него название - "Показывать картинку?" При сохранении после редактирования товара отправлять значение 0 или 1, если установлен `radio` = 1 - значит показываем картинку к текущему редактируемому товару, иначе можно вывести какую-то другую картинку. Далее с помощью `php` при формировании страницы проверяем значения этого поля.

В базе данных создаем поле с названием `visible` с типом данных `ENUM`, а длина/значения = `'0','1'`.

**При редактировании товара в админке:**

```
<div>
    <div>Показывать картинку?</p>
    <input type="radio" name="visible" value="1" <?php if($product['visible']) echo 'checked=""'; ?> /> Да <br />
    <input type="radio" name="visible" value="0" <?php if(!$product['visible']) echo 'checked=""'; ?> /> Нет
</div>
```

Переменную `$product['visible']` соответственно получаете, когда выводите текущую информацию для конкретного товара.

**При добавлении товара в админке:**

```
<div>
    <div>Показывать картинку?</div>
    <input type="radio" name="visible" value="1" checked="" /> Да <br />
    <input type="radio" name="visible" value="0" /> Нет
</div>
```

**Для отображения на странице:**

```
<?php if($product['visible']): //Если картинка отображается, т.е. = 1 ?>
   <a href="ссылка" ><img  src="путь к картинке" ></a>
<?php else: //Если картинка не отображается, т.е. = 0, можно вывести другую картинку, а можно ничего не выводить ?>
   <a href="ссылка" ><img  src="путь к картинке" ></a>
<?php endif; //конец условия ?>
```

Если Вы не управляете редактированием/добавлением товара через админку, то можете просто напрямую управлять полем с названием `visible` через базу данных, в этом страшного ничего нет:)